# PayPal REST API (PHP) not completing transaction

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I'm relatively new to PayPal's REST APIs, so I may be missing a key element here, but what I've done is set up a similar to their example in GitHub:

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php

I follow this pretty close, in that I set the API context to the Client ID and Secret in the app I created on PayPal's Developer site (first using the sandbox and now the live ones).  Here's the part after I create the apiContext:

```
            $payer = new Payer();
            $payer->setPayment_method("paypal");

            $item = new Item();
            $item -> setName($itemDescription)
                    -> setCurrency("USD")
                    -> setQuantity(1)
                    -> setPrice($itemPrice);

            $itemList = new ItemList();
            $itemList->setItems(array($item));

            $amount = new Amount();
            $amount->setCurrency("USD")
                    ->setTotal($itemPrice);

            $transaction = new Transaction();
            $transaction->setAmount($amount)
                    ->setItemList($itemList)
                    ->setDescription($itemDescription);

            $redirectURLs = new RedirectUrls();
            $redirectURLs->setReturnUrl($successURL);
            $redirectURLs->setCancelUrl($cancelURL);

            $payment = new Payment();
            $payment->setIntent("sale");
            $payment->setPayer($payer);
            $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectURLs);
            $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

            try {
                    $payment->create($apiContext);
            }
            catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {

                    print "Exception:  " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
                    var_dump($ex->getData());
                    exit(1);
            }

            # get the redirect URL to pass the user on to PayPal for payment processing
            $redirectURL = "";
            foreach ( $payment->getLinks() as $link ) {
                    if ( $link->getRel() == "approval_url" ) {
                            $redirectURL = $link->getHref();
                            break;
                    }
            }

            // if we get a URL, redirect the user to PayPal's website
            if ( $redirectURL != "" ) {

                    $ppPayID = $payment->getId();

                    # write the ID to the DB
                    $dbQuery = "update members set ppPayID = '" . dbAccess("sanitize", $ppPayID) . "' where memberID = $memberID;";

                    # update the DB
                    $dbResults = dbAccess("query", $dbQuery);

                    //header("Location: $redirectURL");
                    print "<script language='JavaScript'>location.href = '$redirectURL';</script>";
                    exit;
            }
            else {
                    return false;
            }
```

Everything seems to work fine:  I see the item information when passed through to PayPal, I can cancel the transaction and get back to my PHP app via the cancel URL, and I even was able to submit a payment using a live account and get bounced back to my app via the success URL.  Here's what it looks like;

http://example.com/scripts.php?pp=success&memberID=1&token=EC-7G861271R3854####&PayerID=77PAUYJCFJ###

(where the #s are also alphanumeric characters removed just in case)

The problem I have is that though it appears to be successful, the transaction does not show up anywhere on my merchant account, nor does it appear on my personal account.  Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the example was missing a key portion of the transaction process:  executing the payment.  For anyone else struggling with this, here's the necessary piece of code to make this happen:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment

NOTE:  you need to capture both the $payment->getID, as I did in the database, and send URL PayerID back.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to that example. The second portion is to receive that URL that comes back on success, and process the request.

As you can see it in https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/ExecutePayment.php, you need to execute the payment using the ID provided back from the request.

As per your use case, I would go ahead and see if I could merge that page with this, so that it becomes move obvious to the people. If not, I would want to make it very very clear somehow in the sample code, that there is more than that php file in that example.